# Clickable link on specific area of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image of a map It has specific area names on the map but it is all just a PNG image. I would like the user to be able to click a name on the map and be taken to a specific board.

For example, the map has three names on it. Each name is at a different X and Y coordinate, if a user clicks at `X:100, Y:300` or so, they'd be taken to a board whereas if they clicked at `X:400, Y:100`, they'd be taken to another board.

I've thought about using `<canvas>` and `javascript` for this but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for  [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element,

> The HTML `<map>` element is used with `<area>` elements to define an image
>   map (a clickable link area).

And you will need to take a look at [`area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) to see its attributes in order to get the desired outcome

Here is a basic [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jtq7xr5n/)

*The links won't load inside the SO snippet*

```html
<img usemap="#image-clickable" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image">

<map name="image-clickable">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" target="_blank" href="https://google.com/ncr">
</map>
```