# Create a link on an image's area

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I would like to set a region in an image as a clickable area to go to other page.

I am using the following image:

[image]

I would like that the head region had an anchor which points to another page.

I have read:

[I can't click an area map if it is created with `React`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050687/i-cant-click-an-area-map-if-it-is-created-with-react)

[Clickable link on specific area of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610311/clickable-link-on-specific-area-of-an-image)

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

And I have written:

```
import React from 'react';
import CaballoSegmentado from '../images/CaballoSegmentado.PNG';


const CoverPage = () => (
    <div>
        <img className='coverImage' src={CaballoSegmentado} useMap='map'>
        </img>
        <map name='#map'>
            <area alt="" title="" href="/scenePage" shape="poly" coords="1025,12,1035,175,1277,186,1248,26"/>
        </map>
    </div>
);

export default CoverPage;
```

I see that both map and area elements are not being visible on the screen, and inspecting them on the web developer tools I see them offset and with width 0:

[image]

Could you give me a hint, advice, or help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below link https://codesandbox.io/s/o9z00v13yz  usemap is working as expected only..